# Php laravel don't work the same as in local when deployed to shared hosting, cPanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, webdeploy

So, currently, my web-app is working correctly in local. The problem in shared hosting is that when I *clock out*, it automatically changes all the *time clock-out* and *location clock-out* of all the other users as well. Here is the screenshot in local, https://paste.pics/48b6310c2e1bdf728ccedc9ed6fd42ce and here is the screenshot when deployed to shared hosting(cPanel), it is behaving like this, https://paste.pics/f0a9c1aafc62e5edbb0157bf8c1de1e6 .

I've tried reuploading everything for third times, double checking on the controller file in shared hosting, api.php in routes, and the blade.php file in views, resetting all the data and restarting again and it's still the same in shared hosting. I wonder what's wrong ? Please help, I've stucked at this bug since last week friday.

Below are the code taken from hosting using WinSCP

Api.php in routes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserProfileController;


Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

Route::get('getdata', [UserProfileController::class, 'getdata']);
Route::post('getdata/{id}', [UserProfileController::class, 'showdata']);
Route::post('adduser', [UserProfileController::class, 'adddata']);
Route::delete('deleteuser', [UserProfileController::class, 'deleteuser']);
Route::PUT('updateuser', [UserProfileController::class, 'updateuser']);
Route::post('updateuserClockIn',   [UserProfileController::class, 'userClockIn']);
Route::post('updateuserClockOut', [UserProfileController::class, 'userClockOut']);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

function in UserProfileController,

```
public function userClockIn(Request $r)

    {

        $result = [];
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['message'] = "something error";


        $users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['staff_id', 'date_checkIn', 'time_checkIn', 'location_checkIn'])->first();


        $mytime = Carbon::now('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
        $date = $mytime->format('Y-m-d');
        $time = $mytime->format('H:i:s');

        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkIn = $time;
        $users->location_checkIn = $r->location_checkIn;

        AttendanceRecord::updateOrCreate(
            ['staff_id' => $users->staff_id, 'date_checkIn' => $date],
            $users->toArray()
        );

        $result['data'] = $users;
        $result['status'] = true;
        $result['message'] = "suksess add data";

        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

```
public function userClockOut(Request $r)

    {

        $result = [];
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['message'] = "something error";

        $users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['staff_id', 'time_checkOut', 'location_checkOut'])->first();

        $mytime = Carbon::now('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
        $date = $mytime->format('Y-m-d');
        $time = $mytime->format('H:i:s');

        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkOut = $time;
        $users->location_checkOut = $r->location_checkOut;

        // Save the updated data to the database

        AttendanceRecord::updateOrCreate(
            ['staff_id' => $users->staff_id, 'date_checkIn' => $date],
            $users->toArray()
        );

        $result['data'] = $users;
        $result['status'] = true;
        $result['message'] = "suksess add data";

        return response()->json($result);

}
```

blade.php files in views displaying the *History* page,

```
<tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
    @php
    $no = 1
    @endphp
    @foreach ($history as $row)
    <tr>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
        <div class="text-sm text-gray-900"> {{ $no++ }} </div> 
      </td>

      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
        <div class="text-sm text-gray-900"> {{ $row->staff_id }} </div>
      </td>

      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap"> 
        <div class="text-sm text-gray-900"> {{ $row->date_checkIn }} </div> 
      </td>

      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap"> 
        <div class="text-sm text-gray-900"> {{ $row->time_checkIn }} </div>
      </td>
      
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
        {{ $row->location_checkIn }}
      </td>
                        
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
        {{ $row->time_checkOut }}
      </td>
                        
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"> 
        {{ $row->location_checkOut }} 
      </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: You should try condensing down your question to just the relevant parts - and also I would have a go refactoring your code in your controller to make it a little less confusing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: // Maybe?
if ("UTC" != date_default_timezone_get()) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
}

Comment: @BenGooding I tried condensing it to question that are only to relevant parts. Initially i'm planning to have both the code base from local and hosting to be present here. And I want to give the information as much as I can to whomever reading this.

Comment: @Царьвсеямира how do I set it ? but if it is related to the timezone, then why does the time and location check in works but not the time and location checkout ?

Comment: does anyone can help here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's related to the database server timezone.
You can check the database timezone of your local and remote databases and set them (UTC, for exemple).

1. Connect to both databases and check theirs values:

`SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone, @@system_time_zone, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

You must pay attention to the `current_timestamp` or `@@session.time_zone`.

So, you can set them to the expected timezone using the expected timezone on the model.

On the PHP side, you can set the default timezone modifying the connection options (taking in account the databases values):

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
    'timezone'  => '+00:00' // here
],
```

Comment: how do I set it ? but if it is related to the timezone, then why does the time and location check in works but not the time and location checkout ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Maybe?
if ("UTC" != date_default_timezone_get()) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Above there is an answer where it says about the problem with the time zone. I'm not a fan of writing duplicates. I offered a solution for his situation. If he is using hosting he will not be able to change php.ini.

Comment: Thanks, found the solution 2 days ago. It's not a timezone issue but instead was a primary key in database table preventing the data to be updated. I spent more than a week on this problem where it can solved within 20 secs.

Comment: @Царьвсеямира concerning your comment: *Above there is an answer where it says about the problem with the time zone. I'm not a fan of writing duplicates.*: this answer you are referring to could be deleted any time. Writing an explanation how your code works is not duplicating content, unless the code in your answer already is. See some notions how community feels about code only answers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310227/2275490 or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358728/2275490 or this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256402/2275490

Comment: I don't remember if you paid me for this. When the system allows you to write every 30 minutes, there is a desire to leave it. I don't see anything of value in the question or answer. For me, this is a forum for non-professionals. I only answer when I'm bored. If that's not enough for you, I can leave. The door is open.